Folium's "FloatImage" not displayed in Vscode notebook
I try to use FloatImage from folium.plugin to display an image on a Folium map.
When I print the map on a jupyter notebook in VScode, the image is replaced by an alt text.

However, when I save the map as an html, the image is visible.
How to fix the behaviour on vscode ?
This can be reproduced with:
import folium
from folium.plugins.float_image import FloatImage
map = folium.Map()

path = Path('images_folder/image.png')
style = {'bottom': 50, 'left': 50, 'width': -1}

img=FloatImage(path,**style)

map.add_child(img)

